# Android create a folder in phone memory

Tags: android

When I connect my phone to PC I can see different folders, like Movies, Pictures, but also some folders created by apps I have installed, like a "WhatsApp" folder. How can I create my own folder at the same level of Movies, WhatsApp, etc., like other apps do?

I tried with

```
private static final String DNAME = "zip";

rootPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), DNAME);          
if(!rootPath.exists()) {                
 Log.i(TAG, "!rootPath " + rootPath.getAbsolutePath());
 rootPath.mkdirs();         
}
```

but when "zip" folder is not present, it is not created. If I create it via Windows explorer from my PC, it is not seen by the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String folderName = "Movie";
String separator = "/";
String sdcardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
File myFolder = new File(sdcardPath + separator + folderName);
myFolder.createNewFile();
```

Comment: It is working, thank you. Simply, Windows Explorer does not update the list of folders, evan after a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Yes, I did. "zip" folder is not created.